# I need some clarification about sprintf() and array[]

Tags: c, linux, printf

```
char buff[10]={0};
char buff1[6]="xxxxx";
sprintf(buff,"My name is %s");
```

is this a correct array initialization for buff (ie.10)? or I need to initialize with 17.

Comment: It's OK as initialization, but the call to `sprintf()` is lethal – you don't provide a value to be formatted by the `%s` so you have undefined behaviour and anything can happen.  Your array size for `buff` is probably too small, but the code is broken separately from that.

Comment: You should definitely [turn up your compiler's warning level](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/4sojrr) until it gives you something about that `sprintf` call. Mismatched format strings should not get through in this day and age, but compilers go even further than that.

Comment: AADHI A.R, best to pick one language: C or C++ here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're going to write over it with `sprintf` then it doesn't need to contain anything in particular, it just needs to be *large enough to hold the data*.

In other words the `= {0}` is sufficient, and actually optional in this case.

> PSA: **DO NOT USE** functions like `sprintf` that are missing a length argument. Instead use [`snprintf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) and related functions where there is a length argument. Buffer overflow bugs are a huge problem in C if you do not take proper precautions.

The code you should have in C is roughly:

```
size_t buff_size = 255;
char buff[buff_size];
char* name = "Aadhi";

snprintf(buff, buff_size, "My names is %s", name);
```

Where that contains not only a placeholder argument but, importantly, the value that should be used.

In C++ you should skip this entirely and instead:

```
std::string name = "Aadhi";
std::string message = "My name is " + name;
```

Where `std::string` avoids almost all of the problems with buffer overflow bugs.

C++ 20 introduces a new [`std::format`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/format/format) feature which works an awful lot like `sprint` but without all the buffer overflow issues:

```
std::string name = "Aadhi";
std::string message = std::format("My name is {}", name);
```

Comment: Note that the revised array (`char buff[buff_size];`) is a VLA (variable-length array) in C, and illegal in C++ (though `g++` will allow it).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I've added a C++ example to differentiate.

Comment: Although no buffer overrun, without checking the return value of `snprintf()`, code has prevented one problem but still has another: buffer too small indistinguishable from buffer just the right size.  A bug, albeit easier to tame, still exist.